# AT Command Works, But no response

Tags: c#, serial-port, usb, at-command, modem

I've tried sending AT commands by opening a serial port connection and my goal was to send out an SMS. I was able to achieve this and the message was sent out, which is a sign that the WriteLine() method completes successfully. However, i can't seem to get any response in my receive buffers. I've turned on echo by looking at some of the answers over here on stackoverflow.

But still there is no response. I tried waiting out by using Thread.Sleep() and also by using the handler, p_DataReceived. There is still no response.

One example would be the simple "AT" command which should have a response of "ok". But there are no responses at all (i.e. BytesToRead property size is 0)

I'm trying this with D-Link's dwm222 4G LTE USB adapter

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated !

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {



        mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM15");
        mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
        mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
        mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;

        mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        mySerialPort.NewLine = Environment.NewLine;

        mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(p_DataReceived);
        mySerialPort.Open();
        mySerialPort.DiscardInBuffer();
        mySerialPort.DiscardOutBuffer();


        mySerialPort.WriteLine("ATE1"); //turn on echo


        mySerialPort.WriteLine("AT"); //test response


        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        string responseSTR = mySerialPort.ReadLine();

        if (responseSTR.Contains("OK"))  //empty string
        {

            MessageBox.Show(responseSTR);
         }

        this.SendSms("+XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "Hello From C#");

        mySerialPort.Close();

    }

    public void p_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        string s = (sender as SerialPort).ReadExisting();
        buff += s;
        MessageBox.Show(buff);
    }

   void SendSms(string destination, string text)
    { ........}
```

Comment: is your event is firing ? and messagebox is displaying null?

Comment: no event triggered and the responseSTR is empty, i.e responseSTR="".

Comment: Another question: Can you try different  "mySerialPort.NewLine =" settings ? Because "Environment.NewLine" is "\r\n" on Windows (CR +LF). And maybe your modem anwers with "CR" only. Worth a try: mySerialPort.NewLine = "\r" , or whatever is the correct code for this in C# .

Comment: (actually you can find out the "end of line" behavior if you use our Docklight.de tool on COM15 to send an AT command and check the response. It's one of the basic examples shown on the Docklight welcome screen. Free evaluation is enough.)

Comment: thanks oliver, sorry for my late response, i got it to work with the "\r\n" combo. Guess my modem accepts that.

Answer (score 1):

Enabling DTR and RTS filled up the buffer of the serial port object.

```
        mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM17");
        mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
        mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
        mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;

        mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        mySerialPort.NewLine = Environment.NewLine;

        mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(p_DataReceived);

        mySerialPort.Open();
        mySerialPort.DiscardInBuffer();
        mySerialPort.DiscardOutBuffer();
        mySerialPort.DtrEnable = true;    //this solved my problem
        mySerialPort.RtsEnable = true;    //this solved my problem
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should discard buffer each time so you should get a fresh incoming data try this code i have modified in your event handler

```
public void p_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        string s = mySerialPort.ReadExisting();
        buff += s;
        mySerialPort.DiscardInBuffer();
        mySerialPort.DiscardOutBuffer();
        MessageBox.Show(buff);
    }
```

Comment: thank you zain, will use that to clear off the buffer, my main issue was that the buffersize was 0, i.e BytestoRead is 0. I just found out that enabling DTR and RTS was the solution.